# Arduino/C++ An array of pointers with reference

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an array:

```
    #define SELECT_KEY 1
    char *menu_main[] = { "Individual", "OFF", "ON", "Initialise", "Scan", "Read"};
    char *individ_sub_menu[] = { "item1", "Item2" };
    char *inview_menu = &menu_main;
    int selectPos = 0;
    
    int getKeyPress()
    {
       //for purpose of this example
       return 1;
    } 


    void updateMenu()
    {
        uint8_t uiKeyCode = getKeyPress();
        if (uiKeyCode == SELECT_KEY && inview_menu[selectPos] == "Individual")
        { 
           inview_menu = &individ_sub_menu
        }
    }
```

So I'm getting an issue:
*error: cannot convert 'char* (*)[6]' to 'char*' in initialization*

Was hoping that I can switch the reference between those two arrays of char pointers and access the contents based on that inview menu

Comment: I did try that but that yeilded:
error: cannot convert 'char* (*)[6]' to 'char**' in initialization

my aim is to be able to toggle which array I can select and use, not very familiar with C++ but I would hope I can just reference the array of pointers.

I understand that I have a matrix here but I don't need to access the individual elements but the row/column itself. 

I can work through the rest of the errors moving forward but just trying to get this principle down first

Comment: @prog-fh The `&` is incorrect in your comment.

Comment: @john yes, I know (I just cut/pasted, added the star), but it'too late to edit :-(

Comment: note that while arduino compiler may allow those pointers to be `char*` in spite of standard, those string literals are actually statically created arrays and supposed to be `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two arrays have two different types:

```
char *menu_main[] = { "Individual", "OFF", "ON", "Initialise", "Scan", "Read"};
char *individ_sub_menu[] = { "item1", "Item2" };
```

`menu_main` got type `char *[6]` and `individ_sub_menu` got type `char *[2]`. You can't pass both through same interface unless you erase that array type, which can be done by using a pointer to first element of array. You have to pass\store size of array separately:

```
const char *menu_main[] = { "Individual", "OFF", "ON", "Initialise", "Scan", "Read"};
const char *individ_sub_menu[] = { "item1", "Item2" };

struct menu {   
    unsigned     item_count;
    const char **items;
} inview_menu =  { sizeof(menu_main)/sizeof(menu_main[0]) , menu_main };
```

You can create both menus beforehand and pass one or another as a struct witha  shallow copy (assuming menu item strings do not change).

Comment: okay might accept this one ... I didn't understand this at first but seems like this is the way I ended up going about it.  It's looking pretty crazy now, but actually getting my head around this way of programming. Nothing like the languages I'm used to using.

Comment: I did figure that if the strings do change then I created another struct for menu items themselves. So menu struct that you should would instead have item_count and const menuItem **items. It also allowed me to add a few extra properties to the menuItem to bulk it out. Now I just need to google how to add some sort of function in the struct like a "render()" function that each item can call if possible.

Answer (score 2):

`char *menu_main[]` is an array of pointers to `char`.

`&menu_main` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`.

`char *inview_menu` is a single pointer to `char`.

Obviously these are incompatible types.

You probably want `char **inview_menu = menu_main;`

(Note that an array *decays* to a pointer in expressions)

Also, C++ forbids casting string literals to non-const `char*`. So use `const char*`.

```
const char *menu_main[] = { "Individual", "OFF", "ON", "Initialise", "Scan", "Read"};
const char *individ_sub_menu[] = { "item1", "Item2" };
const char **inview_menu = menu_main;
```

Comment: Hey, Yeah, not 100% with this all yet. But as I suspected this is not giving me access to the array of items itself but the individual elements in that array. I assume this is because of the **. Perhaps there's a completely different way that I'm meant to do this. But the arduino documentation recommends creating arrays of strings in this way

I get that they are incompatible types but what is the way to get to the array itself and this instead is giving me the individual elements in the array

Comment: What do you mean? `inview_menu[0]`, `inview_menu[1]` will give `"Individual"` and `"OFF"`, respectively.

Comment: @Tanil you "type erasing" array here because those two arrays have different types (yes, size of array is a part of type). So can't do that anymore, you can have a individual element or a pointer (reference to it)

Comment: @rustyx yeah exactly. I was hoping that in a matrix [][]  I can get matrix[0] or matrix[1] as an example where the first [] is the menu and the [] is the elements. But yeah I've just seen that my understanding of arrays in other languages doesn't translate here as Swift has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

`menu_main` is an array of pointers, that much you realise.

You seem to think that `&menu_main` is a *reference* to `menu_main` but that is incorrect. `&menu_main` is the address of `menu_main` and `&` is the *address-of* operator. It's confusing because the same symbol `&` in a different context does mean a reference. However you may not be using reference in the technical sense that I am.

In any case it doesn't matter, what you have is an array, and you can easily use a pointer to refer to an array, like this

```
char *menu_main[] = { "Individual", "OFF", "ON", "Initialise", "Scan", "Read"};
char *individ_sub_menu[] = { "item1", "Item2" };
char **inview_menu = menu_main;

void updateMenu()
{
    uint8_t uiKeyCode = getKeyPress();
    if (uiKeyCode == SELECT_KEY && inview_menu[selectPos] == "Individual")
    { 
       inview_menu = individ_sub_menu;
    }
}
```

Note that because you have an array of pointers, `inview_menu` is a pointer to a pointer (aka a double pointer). Also note that the address-of operator `&` is not needed in this code.

**EDIT** Also note that `inview_menu[selectPos] == "Individual"` is incorrect. You cannot use `==` to compare C strings, you should use the `strcmp` function instead.

```
    if (uiKeyCode == SELECT_KEY && strcmp(inview_menu[selectPos], "Individual") == 0)
```

Comment: Hey, Yeah sorry about the terminology, not 100% with this all yet. 
But as I suspected this is not giving me access to the array of items itself but the individual elements in that array. I assume this is because of the **.
Perhaps there's a completely different way that I'm meant to do this. But the arduino documentation recommends creating arrays of strings in this way.

Comment: @Tanil This code is not what you'd usually recommend for C++. But I know that you have special restrictions when you program the Arduino. Also note the string comparison error I've added as a edit.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using raw c-arrays in c++ code, and it gets so much easier (note that you should do something different than your "define", but I have kept it):

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    #define SELECT_KEY 1
    vector<string> menu_main = { "Individual", "OFF", "ON", "Initialise", "Scan", "Read"};
    vector<string> individ_sub_menu = { "item1", "Item2" };
    vector<string>* inview_menu = &menu_main;
    int selectPos = 0;
    
    int getKeyPress()
    {
       //for purpose of this example
       return 1;
    } 


    void updateMenu()
    {
        uint8_t uiKeyCode = getKeyPress();
        if (uiKeyCode == SELECT_KEY && (*inview_menu)[selectPos] == "Individual")
        { 
           inview_menu = &individ_sub_menu;
        }
    }
```

Comment: use of c-arrays on a microcontroller and single-board embedded systems is way more preferable  until you implement a placement new allocator, and it's irrelevant to problem with that code.